# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0"

Tags: laravel, azure, web

I upload my laravel project on azure. However when I go to the link I got this error. My project php version is 8.0.0 and my azure php version is 7.4.11. How can I can increase the version on my azure php.

Comment: What azure service are we talking about here? This really depends on how much azure manages vs how much you are managing on the servers.

Comment: Im also having this issue, and asking in Laracasts forum, someone mentioned I should cut and paste vendor directory to somewhere and then to run ```composer update && composer install``` can you say this is a solution, @apokryfos? Thanks.

Comment: It might work, however if a package says it requires PHP 8 then it's very likely it's because it makes use of PHP 8 features. It couldn't hurt to try I guess but the optimal solution is to either figure out how to upgrade your PHP version on azure (if you're using an azure managed platform then it might be a configuration setting otherwise you might need to manually install a new version) or downgrade some dependencies to get your project working with php 7.4

Answer (score 4):

Simply go to `vendor/composer/` , then you will find `platform_check.php` file. Just open it and comment full code. Save it. That's it. You can now use it with lower php verson.

Comment: I know it's not a good approach, but on stagging I have to : )

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your application, you need to update your php version to php version 8

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and now it already solve.

- Check PHP version commend # php --version
- If your PHP 7.4 you need to commend in your laravel project # `composer update`
- If you php >=8.0.0 you need to [install php 7.4](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu/) and commend in your laravel project # `composer update`